# Output BR tag, using simpleXML

Tags: php, newline, simplexml, domdocument

I want to have the text string "hello there" separate in 2 lines.
For this I need the simpleXML to create the "br-tag" in the output file result.xml, but I only get produced the code `&lt;br&gt;`.

```
<?php

// DOMDocument

$dom = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->formatOutput = true;

$html = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement("html"));

$xmlns = $dom->createAttribute('xmlns');
$xmlns->value = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml';
$html->appendChild($xmlns);

// SimpleXML

$sxe = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
$head = $sxe->addChild('head', ' ');
$body = $sxe->addChild('body', 'hello <br> there');

echo $sxe->asXML('result.xml');
```

**Result:**

```
hello <br> there
```

**Wanted Result:**

hello

there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, PHP's SimpleXML extension works only with XML, not HTML. You're rightly mentioning XHTML in your setup code, but that means you need to use XML self-closing elements like `<br />` not HTML unclosed tags like `<br>`.

Secondly, the `addChild` method takes *text content* as its second parameter, not *raw document content*; so as you've seen, it will automatically escape `<` and `>` for you.

SimpleXML is really designed around the kind of XML that's a strict tree of elements, rather than a markup language with elements interleaved with text content like XHTML, so this is probably a case where you're better off sticking to the DOM.

Even then, there's no equivalent of the JS "innerhtml" property, I'm afraid, so I believe you'll have to add the text and `br` element as separate nodes, e.g.

```
$body = $html->appendChild( $dom->createElement('head') );

$body->appendChild( $dom->createTextNode('hello') );
$body->appendChild( $dom->createElement('br') );
$body->appendChild( $dom->createTextNode('world') );
```

Comment: I am using DOMDocument, but wanted to reduce the verbose amount of coding by using SimpleXML and in the situations SimpleXML is not enough I would empower with DOMDocument. After having tried out SimpleXML and realize its restrictions, I decided to stick exlusively to DOMDocument.

Comment: @Toolbox Yeah, in general, I'm a big fan of SimpleXML, but it's generally stronger at reading than writing, and has limited support for the kind of structures commonly encountered in HTML, so DOM is probably the right tool for the job here. :)